# Parenthesis encapsulating several lines in math mode

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I would like to be able to produce parentheses that encapsulate several lines of text in math mode. The context is the following: when typing the solutions to a set of probability exercises, I need to write the probability of an event happening, where the event is described verbally. For instance, the probability of getting a 1, a 3 and a number greater than 4 when throwing three dice would be denoted as $P(\text{getting 1, 3 and a number greater than 4)$, but as you can see, the text is too long and it would be more aesthetically pleasing to me to be able to split it into two or three lines and have the parentheses encompass all of them, as I do when writing by hand.

Is this possible? Note that after this I need to keep writing in the same line. I tried `\left(` and `\right)` and splitting the lines inside with `\text{first line}\\ \text{second line}`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What macro package are you using? In ConTeXt it works. Your double backslashes indicate you do not use ConTeXt...

Comment: @mickep Please excuse my ignorance, but what is a macro package and how do I know which one I am using?

Comment: If you ask those questions you are likely using LaTeX.

Comment: @mickep No idea, I'm just compiling a .tex file in the TexMaker editor...

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being so clear. Your file probably starts with something like `\documentclass{article}` or similar. If so, you use LaTeX.

Comment: @mickep No worries, thanks for the clarification! Yes, that's exactly how it starts.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the line break `\\`.

In particular, `\left` and `\right` don't work with a line break inside. Anyway, they don't always give the best size, and often `\big`, `\Big` `\bigg`, and `\Bigg` variants are preferable. Here I suggest `\bigl( ... \bigr)`.

For small multiline text, you could use the `\substack` command from the `amsmath` package:

```tex
 P \bigl(
  \substack{
    \text{getting 1, 3 and} \\
    \text{a number greater than 4}
  } 
\bigr)
```

If you need more customization (for left align, as example), there is also the `subarray` environment from the same package:

```tex
 P \bigl(
  \begin{subarray}{l}
    \text{getting 1, 3 and}\\
    \text{a number greater than 4}
  \end{subarray}
\bigr)
```

Example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Inline equation: $P \bigl(\substack{\text{getting 1, 3 and} \\ \text{a number
    greater than 4}} \bigr)$.

\medskip

Display equation:
\[
  P \bigl(
  \substack{
    \text{getting 1, 3 and} \\
    \text{a number greater than 4}
  } \bigr)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Multlines with \substack]

#### Edit: use normal text size inside brace

I suggested the `\substack` macro to fit with the math font size. But if you prefer the font size inside the braces to be the same as normal text, use a classical tabular:

```tex
  P \Bigl(
  \begin{tabular}{
      @{\,} % shrink left sep
      c
      @{\,} % shrink right sep
    }
    getting 1, 3 and \\
    a number greater than 4
  \end{tabular}
  \Bigr)
```

I use `@{\,}` to replace left and right spaces with a thin space (it seems that `>` and `<` in tabular definition cannot be used in math mode).

[image: with larger text]

Alternatively, if you don't mind using another package, you can try the [varwidth](https://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) environment, as suggested by  @daleif:

```tex
  P \Bigl(
  \,% thin space before
  \begin{varwidth}{15cm}
    \centering
    getting 1, 3 and \\
    a number greater than 4
  \end{varwidth}
  \,% thin space after
  \Bigr)
```

Comment: If it's just left aligned text, I'd use the varwidth package and env. Give it, say 15cm as its mandatory arg and it will adjust it self to the width of the longest line. Then the `\text` is not really needed unless a guarantee that the text follows context is needed

Comment: @jlab Thank you so much! Is there any way to get the text inside the parentheses to be the same size as the text in the document, not smaller?

Comment: @WildFeather I added two propositions to get normal text size.